# Read txt-file with data and labels into tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, mfcc

I'm relativly new to tensorflow and therefore I'm struggling with the data preparation.
I have a folder with about 500 `.txt` files. Each of these files contain the data and a label of the data. (The data represents MFCCs, which are audio features that get generated for each "frame" of a .wav audio file.)

Each of these files look like this:

```
1
1.013302233064514191e+01
-1.913611804400369110e+01
1.067932213100989847e+00
1.308777013246182364e+01
-3.591032944037165109e+00
1.294307486784356698e+01
5.628056691023937574e+00
5.311223121033092909e+00
1.069261850699697014e+01
4.398722698218969995e+00
5.045254154360372389e+00
7.757820364628694954e+00
-2.666228281486863416e+00

9.236707894117541784e+00
-1.727334954006132151e+01
5.166050472560470119e+00
6.421742650353079007e+00
2.550240091606466031e+00
9.871269941885440602e+00
7.594591526898561984e-01
-2.877228968309437196e+00
5.592507658015017924e-01
8.828475996369435919e+00
2.946838169848354561e+00
8.420693074096489150e-01
7.032494888004835687e+00

...
```

In the first line of each file, I got the label of the data (in this case 1).
In the rest of the file, I got 13 numbers representing 13 MFCCs for each frame. Each frame MFCCs are separated with a newline.

So my question would be whats an easy way of getting the content of all these files into tensors so tensorflow can use them?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is the Optimized way of doing but this can be done as explained in the steps below:

1. Iterate through each `Text File` and append its data to a `List`
2. Replace `'\n'` in each element with `','` because our goal is to create `CSV` out of it
3. Write the Elements of the List whose elements are separated by Commas to a `CSV File`
4. Finally, convert CSV File to `Tensorflow Dataset` using [tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/experimental/make_csv_dataset). Please find this [Tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/csv) on how to convert `CSV File` to `Tensorflow Dataset`.

Code which performs First Three Steps mentioned above is given below:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

# The Folder where all the Text Files are present
Path_Of_Text_Files = '/home/mothukuru/Jupyter_Notebooks/Stack_Overflow/Text_Files'
List_of_Files = os.listdir(Path_Of_Text_Files)

List_Of_Elements = []
# Iterate through each Text File and append its data to a List
for EachFile in List_of_Files:
    with open(os.path.join(Path_Of_Text_Files, EachFile), 'r') as FileObj:
        List_Of_Elements.append(FileObj.readlines())

# Below code is to remove '\n' at the end of each Column
for i in range(len(List_Of_Elements)):
    List_Of_Elements[i] = [sub.replace('\n', ',') for sub in List_Of_Elements[i]] 

Column_Names = ['Label,', 'F1,', 'F2,', 'F3,', 'F4,', 'F5,', 'F6,', 'F7,',
                                                             'F8,', 'F9,', 'F10,', 'F11,', 'F12,', 'F13']    

# Write the Data in the List, List_Of_Elements to a CSV File
with open(os.path.join(Path_Of_Text_Files, 'Final_Data.csv'), 'w') as FileObj:
        FileObj.writelines(Column_Names)
        
for EachElement in List_Of_Elements:
    with open(os.path.join(Path_Of_Text_Files, 'Final_Data.csv'), 'a') as FileObj:
        FileObj.write('\n')
        FileObj.writelines(EachElement)

Path_Of_Final_CSV = os.path.join(Path_Of_Text_Files, 'Final_Data.csv')
Data = pd.read_csv(Path_Of_Final_CSV, index_col = False)
```

To check if our Data is Fine, `print(Data.head())` will output the below data:

[image]